# MsSql - select didnt return values for all columns properly

Tags: sql-server, ssis

i would like to ask maybe  basic question. My SSIS uses SQL query, result is exported to *.csv file. Everything works fine for months (sql select, sql records/results are in csv export) - but yesterday i have  issue:  SSIS ran without error, but in *.csv export one column was without any records(column header is in csv file, but records not) - in another columns there were records (records are from same table  as missing column:().  when i ran SSIS manually again (cca 4 min after), data were in column.  SSIS is deployed and run on same sever as database. **my question is - if there is no error in SSIS  Execution report, data flow task ran correctly, now query returns all data withou editing .... is there any chance to find what caused data loss?  maybe on server log?** 
thank you

Comment: String lenghts? collations? .Net update? OS path? Hard to say, there are too many options I am affraid.

Comment: after 4 min SSIS's export was ok  (without editing package/select, without editing values,) could timeout cause one export column data loss and dont affect other export columns from same sql table?

Comment: We might never know the answer. This is always hard to analyse something which cannot be reproduced.

Comment: My guess, you have a delimiter in your data. Or a missing one.

Comment: @DRastislav I don't see how a timeout would cause this.  I think Jacob H is probably right, but based on working customer support at Microsoft for 6 years, I _know_ that Bartosz X is right - it's damn near impossible to troubleshoot an error that you can't reproduce.